# How to push value in array to store in chrome storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, push

Array push function is creating nested arrays instead of putting values on indexes. its creating  nested item in item instead of adding it in the index of array. I tried many ways but did not find the problem.
i want to add array in each index so that i can retrieve it and create its csv.
I want output like this: item[0]=[title,description,price,image]
item[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwsPQ.png)=[title,description,price,image] and so on as per values entered
here is my js:

```
    $(function(){
        var title='';
            var price='';
            var description='';
            var image='';
            var i=0;
            var product =[];
            var products=[];
        $("#scrape").click(function(){
            chrome.storage.sync.get(["key"],function(result){
                if(result.key!=undefined){  
                    i=result.key;
                }
            });
        chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tabs){
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{todo:"fetch"},function(response){
                     description =response.description;
                     title=response.title;
                     image=response.image;
                     price=response.price;
                     product=[title,price,image,description];
                chrome.storage.sync.get(function(item){
                    if(item["products"] != undefined){
                        item["products"].push(product);
                    }
                    else{
                        item["products"]=product;
                    }
                    //console.log(item);
                    chrome.storage.sync.set({item});
                    i=i+1;
             });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVkji.png)

Answer (score 1):

Think of storage as of a standard JS object that has keys and values. In your case it would make sense to use a key like `products` which would be a standard JS array. The only conceptual difference with using chrome.storage is that you need to read and write the value separately.

```
$('#scrape').click(function () {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {todo: 'fetch'}, response => {
      chrome.storage.sync.get('products', ({products = []}) => {
        products.push([
          response.title,
          response.price,
          response.image,
          response.description,
        ]);
        chrome.storage.sync.set({products});
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: what will happen when there will be no value for key?

Comment: `products = []` will be used.

Comment: Thanks  for the help